# Can Erwin "guess" relationships during reverse engineering (there are no PK/FKs defined in db)

Tags: reverse-engineering, data-modeling

We are embarking upon a Legacy Data Migration project, and in the process of understanding our source database better, we are trying to build a db model out of it.

We dont have any information about the Primary/foreign keys in the db. We are still mining the COBOL code to understand the business better.

However, in our quest to build the db model, we are trying to see if tools like ErWin or PowerDesigner or others can help us "guess" the relationships based on column names etc.  I have the community edition downloaded, and trying the reverse engineering process to see if we can get some worthwhile output, before I go and ask my manager to requisition the purchase of the tool.

So far, I have not got any success with that.  Tried the option wherein it asks about finding relationships using Index / Name, chose name there, but nothing so far.

Could it be that its possible, but I am missing something ?
Is it altogether possible to guess the relationships based on column names ?
Can any other tool do this job ??

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Which DB is the software using? Can you export an example as text and show it here? (of table, row and referenced table)

Comment: We are dealing with db2 on z/os. Tables have encoded names.. e.g. cbt00001 or something like that... we dont have access to data dictionary, and therefore cant query that env for getting more information...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reverse engineer from the DB2 table directly into ERWIN.

You only need a connection to DB2 or get the z/Os dba to provide you with the DDL.

I do not think guessing the relationships is a very good idea when all the information you need is in the DB2 catalog tables. Talk to you DBA.

Comment: As much as I would like to do what you are suggesting, there are costs involved (that of acquiring db2 connect, the driver for IBM DB2).. Its just not possible (commercially), and thats why we had to start thinking of doing it some other way..  Appreciate your inputs...

Comment: Your DBA should be able to provide the DDL for the current system. No need for DB2 connect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more information / examples. In Cobol there is often a naming convention
(e.g. A Table-Id is included in field names at the start / end of the field name) in which
case

```
T1234_Product_code
```

is equivalent to

```
T1323_Product_ID
T1245_Product_Code
```

I suggest investigating (if you have not already) any naming convention.

Comment: thanks for your enquiry.  We have not been able to derive any meaningful naming convention (at least in the tables' column names).